# How do I create this query in C#

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I am trying to perform this same WMI query from a C# function.

```
PS> Get-WMIObject - Namespace root/cimv2/mdm/dmmap - Class MDM_DevDetail_Ext01 - Filter "InstanceID='Ext' AND ParentID='./DevDetail'"
```

This is the C# code but I get an exception 'Invalid query'

What is the correct way to perform this same query in C#?

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap");

scope.Connect();

//Query system for hardware information
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM meta_class where __class = 'MDM_DevDetail_Ext01' 
                         and InstanceID='Ext' and ParentID='./DevDetail'");

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
```

Comment: is there no more information in the exception message?